# Watson Assistant NodeRed Node doesnt accept the new IAM security credentials

Tags: node-red, watson-conversation, watson-assistant, ibm-iam

is there a node red Watson Assistant node update that uses the new IAM security credentials? The existing node asks for username and password which is no longer provide in the new IAM credentials.

Comment: I am using the (IBM Watson) *conversation* node from node-red-node-watson 0.6.6 for quite a while and that is still working fine.

Comment: True that it works in som regions. If you create an Assistant in the Sydney region it uses the new IAM security model. If you create an assistant in theUS region it uses the user/password model. NodeRed+Watson in US works ok. NodeRed_Watson in Sydney does not.

Comment: I suggest that you report this issue in the [node-red forum](https://discourse.nodered.org/).  You will definitely get an answer there.